# My CNN model places all the images in the first class

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to write my first CNN for a college course that determines whether an image is in one of two classes: 0 or 1. My images are located in data/data, the labels used for training are in a separate file,  train_labels.txt and they are for the first 15000 images. The next 2000 images are used for validation and their labels are in validation_labels.txt. Lastly, I want to predict in which class the last 5149 images will be. My issue is that my output places all the images in class 0, which is also the predominant class. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
from glob import glob
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import tensorflow.keras.callbacks as callbacks

train_labels = pd.read_csv("data/train_labels.txt", delimiter=",", header=None, names=["id", "class"], skiprows=1)
val_labels = pd.read_csv("data/validation_labels.txt", delimiter=",", header=None, names=["id", "class"], skiprows=1)

train_labels['id'] = train_labels['id'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>6}.png'.format(x))
val_labels['id'] = val_labels['id'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>6}.png'.format(x))


train_labels["class"] = train_labels["class"].astype(str)
val_labels["class"] = val_labels["class"].astype(str)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_dir = "data/data/"
test_ids = range(17001, 22150)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_labels,
    directory="data/data/",
    x_col="id",
    y_col="class",
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="binary")

val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    val_labels,
    directory="data/data/",
    x_col="id",
    y_col="class",
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="binary")

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=pd.DataFrame({"id": [f"{i:06d}.png" for i in test_ids]}),
    directory=test_dir,
    x_col="id",
    y_col=None,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(scale=1./255),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced', classes=np.unique(train_labels['class']), y=train_labels['class'])
class_weights_dict = dict(enumerate(class_weights))

history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples//train_generator.batch_size,
                    epochs=10,
                    validation_data=val_generator,
                    validation_steps=val_generator.samples//val_generator.batch_size,
                    class_weight=class_weights_dict,
                    )


model.evaluate(val_generator)

preds = model.predict(test_generator)
preds = np.where(preds > 0.5, 1, 0)
output_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(17001, 22150), 'class': preds.flatten()})
output_df.to_csv("data/submission.csv", sep=',', index=False, header=False)
```

I tried changing around the number of epochs, batches, the learning rate etc. but nothing changed so I think the problem has something to do with the model itself

Comment: Why are you using layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(scale=1./255)? you already have ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are most likely related to the imbalanced classes (e.g. if you have >90% of all images in the train set in the class 0).
To fix that you can either work on your train dataset (for the basic approach I can recommend [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/smote-oversampling-for-imbalanced-classification/) or set prediction probability threshold for some valuer lower value (e.g. 0.1 instead of 0.5).
if that won't help please provide target class distribution for all the datasets (train, valid. test) as well as results from your model (output probabilities).